# Which settings do I need in order to use pylint with vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylint

I'm using vs code and want to utilise the python linting feature, however I cannot get it to work.

**settings.json**

```
"python.linting.enabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
```

pep8, autopep8, and pylint are all installed.

Do I need other settings?

Comment: The better way is use PyCharm instead of VS Code.

Comment: if you execute `pylint` from the command line/terminal do you get error messages

Comment: @rioV8 Works perfectly from the command line